# Latencies in Ethernet to RS232 adapter

Tags: ethernet, adapter, rs232

**Requirement:**
I have a software running on my Windows which communicates to an external device using RS232 port. The hardware receives the commands sent from PC and responds back to PC.
When using a plain cable between the computer and hardware, without any adapters, the transmission and reception is completed, say in 50 ms.
When using Ethernet to RS232 adapter the total communication time is (50 + x) ms, with a latency of x ms.

There are lot of products available online, I went through some of the products data sheets. There was information about ethernet and serial communication parameters like Data Bits, baudrate, speed, but nowhere could I find the latency information.

**So far**
I used an adapter ( max. Baudrate 230.4 kbps) to test my Software, but the I ran into Serial Port Timeout exception.

**Question**

On what criteria does this latency depends on?

Does latency depends on the baud rate?

What should I check in the DataSheets to determine (approximate) latency?

Do manufacturers provide latency information?

Comment: Latency is an effect, and refers to the amount of time between the beginning and the completion of a process. As such it varies by perspective, and is never a designed/specified thing (though it is often unavoidable), so its not something any given system can specify.  Its not like a specific cable has a specific "latency" from most perspectives. Propagation delay is the closest and refers to the amount of time it takes for a signal to move from one end of a media to another,  but this is built into the specifications for networking standards like 802.3/Ethernet or in your case RS-232.

Comment: From my understanding you're converting a RS232 signal to a Ethernet data stream and back to a RS232 signal, right? As such it would at least be the delay that is needed for the convert whatever is defined as a command an package/unpackage it ... twice (once for each end).

Answer (score 0):

> On what criteria does this latency depends on?

Buffering, data framing, transmission, protocol and timeout I would guess to be the main ones.

As other commenters mentioned, at minimum you have protocol translation delays. You would need to account for the endpoint and bridge data buffering, recoding, protocol overhead and transmission time.  The latency will be affected by whether or not a full frame of data is buffered before transmission and what the internal timeouts might be.  These can be configured in some devices.

It will also depend on whether the Ethernet protocol is using UDP, TCP or a custom protocol.  It will depend on whether the protocol supports retransmit and whether it adds additional integrity or signaling information.  Again these can be configured in some devices.  Without having looked I would guess that low-end devices would tend to use UDP without any integrity or retransmit and tend to buffer a full UDP frame of data with some internal timeout to send a partial frame if the data flow stops.

> Does latency depends on the baud rate?

It really depends on what latency you are measuring.  The difference in serial data rates will probably affect your *throughput* more significantly than your *latency*.  Yes, it does affect latency but keep in mind that at 9600bps a byte takes about 1ms to transmit.

> What should I check in the DataSheets to determine (approximate)
>   latency?
>
> Do manufacturers provide latency information?

Bridges for industrial applications do sometimes provide information about latency and/or throughput.  For example [one such product page](https://www.perle.com/products/rs232-to-ethernet.shtml) quotes a latency of 2ms.  There are also some company sponsored testing reports such as this [2003 competitive comparison](http://www.comtrol.com/elements/uploads/files/Veritest-performance.pdf) or [this 2002 report](https://www.digi.com/pdf/latencytest.pdf) that compares latencies for several devices. The latencies in their test range from a few milliseconds up to 861ms average.

Anyway it sounds like your underlying problem is serial port timeout rather than a latency problem. From what little you have said, I tentatively suspect a software or configuration error.  There are typically several timeouts specified in a serial interface library, such as interbyte timing, multibyte read time and write time.  Also there are buffer overflow errors if the buffered data are not being emptied fast enough. As you may know, you can typically adjust or disable each timeout in your serial client.

I would start by identifying where the error is originating.  You might also turn the speed down to 9600 since cheap adapters don't always perform well at their rated maximums.